# Using an equation to get back an array that isn't "nil."

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to gather data from my db in the form of an array so I use the `inject` method to get a sum of my duration attribute. However, I can't get an array of integers because duration is a function, not a value. But I don't know how to save it as a value when it depends on a range of dates. Here's what I've tried:

In the console:

```
oldman = Employee.first
```

Okay, so duration works here..

```
oldman.furlough.first.duration
=> 1
```

And here...

```
oldman.furlough.last.duration
=> 4
```

But when I try to use 'all' to get an array...

```
oldman.furlough.all.duration
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `duration' for #<Array:0x007fd75651c3d8>
```

So I've tried...

```
oldman.furloughs.all(:select => :duration).collect(&:id)
=> [nil, nil]
```

and...

```
oldman.furloughs.pluck(:duration)
=> [nil, nil]
```

which both bring back the format I want, but not the information.

Here's the Furloughs model with duration equation:

```
class Furlough < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  def only_weekdays(range)
    range.select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size    
  end

  def psb_holidays
    Holidays.between(date_from, date_to, :us, :observed).size
  end

  def duration
    (only_weekdays(date_from..date_to) - psb_holidays)
  end
end
```

Comment: `Furlough.all.collect(&:duration)` doesn't work?

Comment: Just tried that, it works but it includes all durations for all employees when I will need to separate it by employee_id.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "separate it by emp id"; are you trying to build a hash of id => duration? An array of [id, duration]? Both are relatively straight-forward, the array could be done w/ `collect`, the hash via `each_with_object`.

Comment: "Employees" each have a number of "Furloughs", and I'm attempting to add up the total Furloughs for each individual Employee (each Furlough has an employee_id that matches with an Employee). I'm looking for something that outputs just like what you gave me, but for each individual employee, and then I'm planning on pairing it with this: insertsweetcodehere.inject(0) { | memo, n | memo + n }

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly in the console: Employee.first.furloughs.collect(&:duration). In my model, should I write something like self.furloughs.collect(&:duration) in my employee model (where the equation is currently) so it will work for each employee?

Comment: That would certainly work. Depending on your needs it might not be particularly efficient.

Comment: When I finally turn this project in my supervisors will help me refactor everything into something that actually makes sense, but at my level, yeah, I'm just happy it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dave's help I found this to work:

```
Employee.first.furloughs.collect(&:duration)
```

In my `Furlough` model, I have a new method defined as follows:

```
def vacation_days_used
  self.furloughs.collect(&:duration).inject(0) { | memo, n | memo + n } 
end
```

Which gives me separate sums of each employee's furloughs.